# Excel 2007: View/focus on last rows when opening the workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, macros, focus

I have about 4700 rows on my sheet. When I open the workbook, it always focuses on the first rows. I want it to focus/view on the last rows of the sheet instead. It doesn't have to select. In fact I prefer if it doesn't select an active cell. I just want it to view the last rows instead. Also note that this is a dynamic table. So things will be added at the bottom of the list.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will show the same view you had when saving (unless a macro runs and changes it).

So you just hit CTRL+END and then Save, and it will stay there.